# How to use CASE without adding new column to table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to change column value by `CASE` command depending on condition without giving adding a new column to table?

The only way I know is by adding new column:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
    ,CASE
        what='costs' THEN amount*(-1)
    ELSE
    sales
    END AS NewAmount
FROM t1
```

Is there a way to get the results as on the picture below? Note that sometimes the condition is specified by values in more than one column (what=costs AND country=Atlantida)

[image: case]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is way,
Instead of `select *`, use required column names only.

```
SELECT 
    t1.what
    ,CASE
        WHEN what='costs' THEN amount*(-1)
    ELSE
    sales
    END AS Amount
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 4):

Select just the columns that you want:

```
SELECT t1.what, 
       (CASE WHEN what = 'costs' THEN amount*(-1)
             ELSE sales
        END) AS Amount
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want **amount** when not cost?

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
    ,CASE when what='costs' THEN amount*(-1)
     ELSE
        amount
     END AS NewAmount
FROM t1
```